# git p4 clone failure: ValueError bad marshal data

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I am taking a shot at using Git-P4 to make day to day changes on a project a little easier. While following the Git-p4 usage in the Git wiki when I come to the **git p4 clone** phase I receive the following error(paths purposely removed):

```
Importing from //****/****/mainline@all into mainline
Initialized empty Git repository in /****/****/.git/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/****/****/git/2.3.5/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3297, 
  in ? main()
File "/****/****/git/2.3.5/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3291, 
  in main if not cmd.run(args):
File "/****/****/git/2.3.5/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3165, 
  in run if not P4Sync.run(self, depotPaths):
File "/****/****/git/2.3.5/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 2927, 
  in run self.loadUserMapFromCache()
File "/****/****/git/2.3.5/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 908, 
 in loadUserMapFromCache self.getUserMapFromPerforceServer()
File "/****/****/git/2.3.5/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 883, 
    in getUserMapFromPerforceServer for output in p4CmdList("users"):
File "/****/****/git/2.3.5/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 480, in p4CmdList
  entry = marshal.load(p4.stdout)
ValueError: bad marshal data`
```

Not sure if this means I have to make a change to the p4 print command? Anyone else in the community come across this error? And/Or have suggestions?

**EDIT**
Output example

```
p4 users
a00000 <someone@email.com>             (Someone Name) accessed 2015/05/01 15:26:31, updated 2008/11/15 14:00:25, pwd [enabled]
faken  <another@email.com>       (Someones Name(CON)) accessed 2015/05/01 15:26:31, updated 2008/11/15 14:00:25, pwd [NOT SET]
```

Comment: Please provide p4 version and the output of p4 users in your question. Omit any sensitive information from the command's output.

Comment: version: P4/LINUX26X86/2014.1/821990.
The user list contains all sensitive info, is there something specific you would need?

Comment: Could you show how the output of the command is formatted?

Comment: Please take a look at the output and check if there is any non-ascii character there, like accented words for example.

Comment: Command looks like the following: git p4 clone //depotName_depot/Upper_Level/Project/mainline

Comment: I was talking about `p4 users` command :)

Comment: ahh my bad. See the question edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78104/discussion-between-vitor-and-nope).

Answer (score 0):

Git-p4 depends directly on the `p4` command, so no wrapper script can be used in its place. If such a wrapper script is required, then it should at least be able to correctly pass the `-G` argument to the underlying `p4` call. Preferably it should also support all `p4` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) does improve `p4CmdList()`, because before that, `git p4` did not handle non-ASCII client name well.

See [commit d205483](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d205483695366803e912da6ae24380c33c293467) (21 Jul 2022), and [commit 34f67c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34f67c9619b56ab4718427c1a31071641f0dccdb) (08 Jul 2022) by [Kilian Kilger (`cohomology`)](https://github.com/cohomology).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e59acea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e59acea3f0752ddfdcaab08b54dc0f84c7ab66e6), 01 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d205483695366803e912da6ae24380c33c293467): refactoring of p4CmdList()
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kilian Kilger</sup>

> The function `p4CmdList` executes a Perforce command and decodes the marshalled python dictionary.
> Special care has to be taken for certain dictionary values which contain non-unicode characters.
> The old handling contained separate hacks for each of the corresponding dictionary keys.
> This commit tries to refactor the coding to handle the special cases uniformely.